# Update fields based on If-Else condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, case

I have `Table` A (source) that needs to update `Table` B (target), depending on a few rules. There is a matching key between both Tables (which is `email`).

When field `check1` equals "Hello" and `check2` equals "World" from `Table` B, then I want to update three fields.

However, if field `check1` equals "Hello" and `check2` equals "Pineapple" from `Table` B, then  I want to update just one field.

Pseudo code below:

```
SELECT Name, City, Phone
FROM A

IF B.check1="Hello" AND B.check2="World" THEN
    update B.Name = A.Name, 
    update B.City = A.City,
    update B.Phone = A.Phone

ELSE IF B.check1="Hello" AND B.check2="Pineapple" THEN
    update B.Name = A.Name

ENDIF

INNER JOIN B
ON A.email = B.email
```

Table examples:

TABLE A

```
+-----------------------+------+------+-------------+
| Email                 | Name | City | Phone       |
+-----------------------+------+------+-------------+
| customer1@example.com | John | NYC  | 123-123-123 |
+-----------------------+------+------+-------------+
|                       |      |      |             |
+-----------------------+------+------+-------------+
```

TABLE B

```
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
| Email                 | check1 | check2 | Name | City | Phone       |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
| customer1@example.com | Hello  |  World |      |      |             |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
|                       |        |        |      |      |             |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
```

RESULT (IF first case)

```
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
| Email                 | check1 | check2 | Name | City | Phone       |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
| customer1@example.com | Hello  |  World | John | NYC  | 123-123-123 |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
|                       |        |        |      |      |             |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't conditionally update a column, you either have to update the column or not. But you can conditionally change the value using a [`case expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Using your conditions you can either set the specified columns to new values OR keep the old values as follows.

```
update B set
  [Name] = case when B.check1 = 'Hello' and B.check2 in ('World','Pineapple') then A.[Name] else B.[Name] end
  , City = case when B.check1 = 'Hello' and B.check2 in ('World') then A.City else B.City end
  , Phone = case when B.check1 = 'Hello' and B.check2 in ('World') then A.Phone else B.Phone end
from TableB B
inner join TableA A on A.email = B.email;
```

Note: You can do the same thing with `iif` (its just shorthand for `case`), I prefer `case`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't this way.

Personally, I would do many updates, but if you insists to do it in one would be :

```
set
b.Name = a.Name,
b.City = iif(b.check2 = "something", a.City, b.City),
b.Phone = iif(b.check2 = "something", a.Phone, b.Phone)
```

Comment: Why would you do multiple updates? The way you have done it will perform much better.